# How to remove '0' values from the text graph in QGIS

Tags: qgis, diagram

I am trying to do some distribution maps using QGIS with text diagrams. The problem is that the graph shows also all the cases with No data or '0'. I do not want these in my graph. Any ideas where I can find the function that removes the 0 values from the graph?

Answer (score 3):

Try using CASE WHEN in the expression:

"if field is NULL or 0 then show an empty string '' else show field value":

```
CASE WHEN "field123" IS NULL THEN '' 
ELSE CASE WHEN "field123" = 0 THEN '' 
ELSE "field123" END END
```

[image]